# Accessing data in D3 from a click event

Tags: d3.js

I have this svg that has a circle inside. The circle has been created with the data object from "myData".
The circle has a click event, but when I try to console.log() the data appended to this circle, I get the following error message : Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

The below code can be tested here : https://jsfiddle.net/zsv21byf/

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="cv">
</svg>




const myData = [
{id:"Zoox",type:"Tier1",tags:"AD_Driverless",technology:"",market:"Robotaxi",valuation:"",description:"Zoox is an AI robotics company that provides mobility as-a-service and self-driving car services.",country:"US",region:"North America",image:"https://res-4.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_170,w_170,f_auto,b_white,q_auto:eco/kpc7mmk886nbbipbeqau"}
]

var svg = d3.select("#cv")
 .attr("height",300)
 .attr("width", 300)
 .style("border", "1px solid red")

        
    const node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 5)
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(myData)
        .join("circle")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .attr("cx", 100)
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .on("click", function() { 
            console.log(d.id)
        });



#cv{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: `.on("click",function(d) {... ` not `.on("click",function() {...`

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I needed to access the data through d3.select(this).

In my case, this is what needed to be typed in the console.log :

```
console.log( d3.select(this).data()[0] )
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that any future readers can learn from it.